# Group of buttons in Movie clip doesn't trigger-AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, movieclip

I basically lumped all the buttons in a Movie Clip so that i don't have to individually make a MouseClicked function for a lot of buttons.
It works when you test it on it's own but when i put it in another scene that redirects to it it shows an error

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

this is my code for it

```
  buttonsClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleButtons, false, 
   0,true);

    /** Button Handler */
    function handleButtons(e:Event)
    {
         /** e.target is the actual button that is being pressed. */
         trace(e.target.name);

    timer1.start();
    wrongBush.visible = true;
    fl_SC = s.play();
        stop();

    }
```

Comment: which line is throwing the error?   From this code, it means that either `buttonClip`,  `timer1` `wrongBush` or `s` are null.

Comment: its buttonsClip according to debug but i don't really get why it does that.

Comment: heres the other errors: at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
 at flash.display::Sprite()
 at flash.display::MovieClip()
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at map_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame()[map_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:6]

Comment: There isn't much help that can given with the information available.  Make sure that where this code runs `buttonsClip` exists and has that instance name.

Comment: I fixed it by turning buttonsClip into a button instead of movieclip. tnx all for responding